# Use Excel Macro in a different Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I want to create a Menu-sheet from where I can start different macros for different sheets. But the code doesn't work when i start is from a differet sheet. The code only works correctly when I start it from the "1. Stock & Demand" sheet

```
Sub NeuerTag()

'Abfrage ob der Tag eingefügt werden soll, No = QUIT'
If MsgBox("Möchtest du die Tabelle vorbereiten?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

'Kopiert die letzten 3 Spalten des Tabellenblattes'
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(Lastcol - 1).Resize(, 1).Select
Selection.Copy

'Wählt die erste freie Spalte aus und fügt das zuvor kopierte ein'
Sheets("1. Stock & Demand").Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Aktuelles Datum einfügen'
Sheets("1. Stock & Demand").Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-1, 0).Select
Selection.Value = Date

'Wählt die zuvor kopierten Spalten aus und nimmt die Formeln raus'
With Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")
Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Columns(Lastcol - 3).Resize(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End With
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance & Greetings

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is? I don't see a question anywhere.

Comment: I can't use the Macro in the Home-Sheet. I can only use the Macro in the sheet "1. Stock & Demand".

Comment: Most code should go into standard code modules as opposed to sheet modules (which are typically used for event handlers).

Comment: Also, you probably want `Lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` rather than `Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` (note the dot before `Cells`)

Comment: Thank you, Excel doesn't do the right things if I start the macro in a different sheet... I tried it with select but I dont want excel to switch the sheets

Comment: Why dont you want excel to switch the sheets? Just start with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`, activate Sheet1 and use `ActiveSheet` instead of `Sheets("1. Stock & Demand")` each time.

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the comments, there are at least two issues

1) When you say "I want to create a Home-Sheet from where I can start different macros for different sheets." you give the impression that you want to use the code module for "Home-Sheet" to contain the macros. Most macros don't belong in such sheet modules. Instead they belong in standard code modules. `Insert` one in the VBA editor and put it there.

2) It doesn't matter that a line like

```
Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column rather than Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

is within the scope of a `With` statement. Unless you prefix `Cells` with a dot, VBA will interpret the `Cells` in the context of the active sheet. Instead, use:

```
Lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column rather than Lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Similar remarks hold for `Columns`.

Comment: The code is in a module. But i want to create a sheet from where I start all macros. Those macros will then start working in different sheets. The idea behind this is to not have to switch between those sheets. ONE Sheet with Buttons to start all macros (like a menu).

Comment: What exactly is the problem. Isn't it fixed by making sure that you are referring to cells and columns in the target sheet rather than the active sheet?

Comment: As @John said about prefixing the cells with a dot so it references the `With` statement.  Throughout your code you're using `Sheets ("1. Stock & Demand")`.  Call it a hunch if you like, but this could be why it's only working on that sheet.

Comment: Hi Darren. It's should only work on the sheet 1. Stock & Demand. But I want to start the macro from a different sheet. `Sheets("1. Stock & Demand").Range("F3:ZZ3").End(xlToRight).Offset(-2, 1).Paste`is one of the problems. I'm sorry but my VBA skills are very limited.

Comment: @Bluesector   Using `select` and `paste` to transfer values is usually not a good idea. Instead just assign the source values to the target range with a line that looks like `target.value = source.value` where `source` and `target` are the appropriate range references. Also, it isn't a bad idea to declare a worksheet variable (say `ws`) and have the line `set ws = Sheets ("1. Stock & Demand")` and just prefix all your references with `ws` rather than using so many `with` statements.